# How to copy the entire values of array strings into a single string along with the empty spaces?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm using eclipse, so I have this argument on the run configuration:

> hello   HELLO hello

Apparently, it's on String[] args. Is there a method that can concatenate all the array values ALONG with the empty spaces between them?

I have tried splicing the arrays into a char arrays, used the toString method(garbage value for some reason), and even StringBuilder. But it always gives values but not the spaces itself. @@

Answer (score 4):

You can use the String.join method:

```
String[] arr = {"hello", "HELLO", "hello"};
System.out.println(String.join(" ", arr));
```

[String#join](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) is available in Java 8.

Using StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for (String str : arr) {
  sb.append(sep);
  sb.append(str);
  sep = " ";
}
System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thanks, forgot to add that comment.

Answer (score 1):

Well if I understood your question correctly, you have such array:

`string[] str = new string[3] { "Hello", "HELLO", "hello"};`

If you want them to have spaces between each words you can do something like

```
string output = "";

    for(int i = 0; i< str.length; i++)
    {
          if(i + 1 != str.length)
          {
              output += str[i] + " ";
          }
          else
          {
              output += str[i];
          }  
    }
```

Comment: Well it should demonstrate the point in Java too, in my opinion.

Comment: Just some problems with this code, you using `str` even though it is an array. So seems like you forgot the `index` values when using `output += str [ i ] + " ";`. Moreover, it is Java, hence,  `Length` should be `length`, with small `l` not capital `L' :-). Though rest of the logic is corrent

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I do not know what I was thinking when I wrote the answer for the first time. I believe it is correct now.

Answer (score 1):

```
try this 

 public static void main(String[] args)
{
    String concated = "";
    for(String arg:args){
        concated+=arg+" ";
    }

    System.out.println(concated);
}
```